# How to remove Installanywhere installation from registry

Tags: installation, installanywhere

I'm trying to install a tool that was packaged by installanywhere,

The installation doesn't start because the install is detecting a previous version of this toll.

[image]

I removed any installation of that tool from: **"Add\remove program"**

and removed any folders containing this tool , But I can still see it's registered in the Registry.

[image]

**How can I remove it from there so I can install my tool?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this tool,

Which is great for uninstalling:

[Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)

[image]